# C++ Can't Return A Vector of Textures

Tags: c++, sfml

I have a class that keeps track of objects I've declared. This class also has a vector as a member. I add textures through a function (probably, there is a leak). I am probably doing a mistake about c++ itself, not sfml.

in Item.h:

```
    #ifndef ITEM_H
    #define ITEM_H

    class ItemTexture {
        public:
            static std::vector<ItemTexture*> textures;
            std::vector<sf::Texture*> variation;
            ItemTexture(std::string file);
            void addTexture(std::string file);
            static sf::Texture getTexture(int id, int no) {
                return *textures[id]->variation[no]; //Program crashes here
            }
            static void declare_textures();
    };

#endif
```

in the Item.cpp:

```
#include "Item.h"
std::vector<ItemTexture*> ItemTexture::textures;
ItemTexture::ItemTexture(std::string file)
{
    sf::Texture *tex = new sf::Texture;
    tex->setSmooth(false);
    tex->loadFromFile(file);
    variation.push_back(tex);
    textures.push_back(this);
    delete tex;
}
void ItemTexture::addTexture(std::string file)
{
    sf::Texture *tex = new sf::Texture;
    tex->setSmooth(false);
    tex->loadFromFile(file);
    variation.push_back(tex);
    delete tex;
}
```

This doesn't give any error messages, program crashes at the line return *textures[id]->variation[no];

Comment: That is because you delete the textures after pushing them back to the vector, so the vector contains all deleted Texture* s.

Comment: *This doesn't give any error messages* -- All this means is that the C++ code is valid.  It has nothing to do with whether the logic of the program is correct or not.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Not even that. Clearly, OP deleted something then referenced it, which is UB and thus not correct C++ code. Compiling without error is a guarantee that a *very narrow class of problems* do not exist in the code.

Comment: And C++ allows such imperfect code to compile with no error.  I see a lot of newbies posting the line "it compiles ok, however...", as if the "it compiles ok" means really anything.

Comment: "This doesn't give any error messages," - Unfortunately the absence of compiler warnings/errors does *not* mean your code is valid or doing anything sensible. There are *lots* of things in C++ that the language will let you write and a compiler will compile, that still is nonsensical or has Undefined Behaviour (no diagnostic required). "It compiles" is a *really low* bar for correctness and *far* from enough to show absence of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities for crash in your code at `*textures[id]->variation[no];`

1. You must be creating an object of `ItemTexture` in stack and then the constructor of `ItemTexture` is pushing back `this` pointer to the vector `textures`. If the object you created goes out of scope, the vector `textures` will have a dangling pointer since the object it is pointing to is already destroyed. Or you could be deleting it like you have done with sf::Texture as explained in second possible reason below. This causes `*textures[id]` part of `*textures[id]->variation[no];` to cause crash.

Solution: Allocate it dynamically and don't delete it till you are done with that( calls  like `getTexture()`).

2. You are creating object Texture dynamically using `sf::Texture *tex = new sf::Texture;` and deleting that with `delete tex;`. So whatever you pushed with `variation.push_back(tex);` becomes dangling pointer. `variation` is full of dangling pointers and when you access it, you application crashes. This causes `variation[no]` part of `*textures[id]->variation[no];` to cause crash if above one is not the issue.

Solution: Remove `delete tex;` and release it in destructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your first answer seems to be correct, I wasn't calling ItemTextures dynamically. This was a stupid mistake, I'm still a newbie, thank you!